# Subset function does not have type as argument?

Tags: r, subset

I'm following descriptions from a book and it says that subset has a type argument as shown below. However, R keeps throwing the following error message:

```
"Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'type' not found"
```

Someone please help indicate why the error arises with the following code:

```
spam <- subset(sms_raw, type == "spam")
```

Factors:

```
'data.frame':   5572 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ï..v1: Factor w/ 2 levels "ham","spam": 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what the arguments of `subset()` are, run:

```
?subset
```

You will then see that one of its arguments is called `subset` and is a

> logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep

This is what you want (you want to subset rows which test positive for `type == "spam"`).

If your data frame had a variable called `type`, then your code would work. So rename the variable containing the values `"ham"` and `"spam"` to `type` or replace `type` by the name of that variable in your code.